# How to create animated glow effect on Button Hover with C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

I am creating a **CustomButton** control for my application. Now, What I want to do that when the mouse goes on the button it should show glow effect and when mouse leave it should get back to normal. But the glow effect should not displayed immediately. It should display with animation. just like **Chrome Browser Tab Page**. I have tried this logic in the button control.

This is my logic. But, I think this is not a proper way. please suggest proper way to get glow effect.

```
private void ShowGlow()
{
    for (int i = 0; i<50; i+= 5)
    {
         Sleep(100);
         Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
         Color color = Color.FromArgb(i, 150,150,25);
         g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(color), this.ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```

**Additional Details**
Visual Studio 2005, Windows XP, Windows Form Controls

Comment: I strongly recommend WPF for this. winforms doesn't support animations, or effects, or anything like that.

Comment: My application is a windows form application with .net framework 2.0 and i cannot convert it to WPF application.

Comment: @HighCore I agree with you that winform doesn't support this. but that doesn't mean we've to compromise; if we spend time we could do that.

Comment: Any other way to create button like that in any other language? So i can use it in my application.

Comment: These may help you http://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/ and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548769/Animator-for-WinForms

Comment: Some unnecessary harshing on win forms from @HighCore.  It may not be as modern as WPF, and isn't designed for web projects at all, but drawing using GDI+ is fast and very versatile.  You do have to override the OnPaintBackground in order to prevent flicker in some cases, but this is not a "hardware acceleration" issue.

Comment: @Ted `drawing using GDI+ is fast and very versatile`... Yeah, I'm pretty sure it is so versatile you can really do things like [**this**](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/) in winforms... Please...

Comment: Cool stuff @HighCore :-).  No question that WPF supports some cool GUI animations and likely has effects that GDI+ just can't keep up with.  However if you need to do serious CAD or GIS rendering, loading up WPF geometries with tens of thousands of coordinates will cause your app to basically grind to a halt, whereas GDI+ can render the same 2D shapes with comparative ease.  Also developers frequently don't control what technology they get to use, so just giving up completely just because you are developing in Forms is not a useful approach.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you a simpler method.
Create two images, with glow effect and without.
And use this code.

**On MouseEnter:**

```
private void MyButton_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyButton.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.WithGlow; 
}
```

**On MouseLeave:**

```
private void MyButton_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyButton.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.WithoutGlow; 
}
```

This is what I usually do in my projects.

Comment: How do you make it animated? I want to make it animated just like a fade in and fade out effect. Please read my question i have already mentioned it.

Comment: Could you show us the button images with and without glowing effect?

Comment: I am not using any image to create button. I am drawing it using graphics object. because, the theme of button should be different for each button object.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code that uses timers and overrides the OnPaint method.  It skips by 10 instead of 1 because I was afraid you wouldn't see the effect fast enough otherwise.  The Timer interval is in milliseconds and was set to 100 because that was what you were using in your original example for sleep.  If you need the effect to work faster, you can reduce the interval.  If it should be slower, you can increase the interval, or decrease how much you increment alpha with each tick.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LicensePlate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The GlowButton class
    /// </summary>
    public class GlowButton : Button
    {
        #region Fields
        Timer timer;
        private int alpha;
        Color color;

        #endregion

        #region Events

        #endregion

        #region Constructor


        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new instance of the GlowButton class.
        /// </summary>
        public GlowButton()
        {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 100;
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        }


        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Only used if you need something else to trigger the glow process
        /// </summary>
        private void ShowGlow()
        {
            timer.Start();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Start the timer and reset glow if the mouse enters
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Start();
            alpha = 0;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Reset the glow when the mouse leaves
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            alpha = 0;
            color = BackColor;
            Invalidate();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Override paint so that it uses your glow regardless of when it is instructed to draw
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pevent"></param>
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pevent);
            if (alpha > 0)
            {
                using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(color))
                {
                    pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, this.ClientRectangle);
                }
            }

            //base.OnPaint(pevent);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Use a timer tick to set the color and increment alpha
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            alpha+=10;
            color = Color.FromArgb(alpha, 150, 150, 25);
            if (alpha > 50) {
                timer.Stop();
            }

            Invalidate();
        }

        #endregion




    }
}
```