# Button Image that has a glow effect

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, button

I'm using WinFroms. In my application i have a button that I'm trying to manipulate. This button has an image. In Mouse down event it seems like the image is being pushed downward and then in mouse up event the image seems like its back to its normal size.

Now I'm trying to create a little glow effect when you hover over the image. How can i achieve that?

The button properties is :

Flat Appearance

Flat style = Flat

Border size = 0

Mouse Down Back Color = Transparent

Mouse Over Back color = Transparent

Here is my Code:

```
    Image Check = Resources.checkmark_icon;

    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int Check_Width = Check.Width + ((Check.Width * -20) / 100);
        int Check_Height = Check.Height + ((Check.Height * -20) / 100);

        Bitmap Check_1 = new Bitmap(Check_Width, Check_Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Check_1);
        g.DrawImage(Check, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, Check_1.Size));
        button1.Image = Check_1;
    }

    private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int Check_Width = Check.Width;
        int Check_Height = Check.Height;

        Bitmap Check_1 = new Bitmap(Check_Width, Check_Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Check_1);
        g.DrawImage(Check, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, Check_1.Size));
        button1.Image = Check_1;
    }

    private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: this is actually quite simple you need to create `1` image that has no `GLOW` and a `2nd Image` that has a `Glow` effect also do a google search on the following `How to create animated glow effect on Button Hover with C#` there are literally `Tons` of examples online here is a good one to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138888/how-to-create-animated-glow-effect-on-button-hover-with-c

Comment: Thank you for your help. @MethodMan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a glow effect on the image in the button using 2 images like MethodMan suggested.

The 1st image is a glow check mark.

The 2nd image is a check mark that does not glow.

```
    private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Image = Resources.glow_Check_mark_PNG;
    }

    private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Image = Properties.Resources.checkmark_icon;
    }
```